# How to integate anything-occur within isearch mode

Tags: emacs

I like [`anything.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) a lot. The anything UI is wonderful.

I also use `isearch` very often, and it provides the keybinding <kbd>M-s o</kbd> to invoke `occur` using the `isearch` input string. But native occur mode is not powerful enough.

In `occur-mode` you cannot filter result again. And jumping function is basic too.

I find [`anything-occur`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything-config.el) is more powerful than `occur`, you can filter result, jump a position in anything style.

But there is a problem , How to integrate `anything-occur`?  My last attempt is:

```
(defun occur-in-isearch ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search isearch-case-fold-search))
    (occur (if isearch-regexp isearch-string (regexp-quote isearch-string)))))
```

I replace `occur` with `anything-occur`, but it is no use. `anything-occur` is a defun which takes no parameters.  I cannot pass the isearch string to `anything-occur`.

How might I integrate `anything-occur`? Or is there a better way to use `anything-occur` within `isearch-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of anything, but this code does 99% of what you want.  The only caveat is that the initial input string doesn't get properly updated when you type <kbd>backspace</kbd>.  I don't know why that is.  Everything else works seems to work as expected.

```
(eval-after-load "isearch"
  '(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-s o") 'isearch-anything-occur))

(defun isearch-anything-occur (regexp &optional nlines)
  "isearch anything occur"
  (interactive
   ;; from isearch-occur
   (list
    (cond
     (isearch-word (concat "\\b" (replace-regexp-in-string
                                  "\\W+" "\\W+"
                                  (replace-regexp-in-string
                                   "^\\W+\\|\\W+$" "" isearch-string)
                                  nil t)
                           "\\b"))
     (isearch-regexp isearch-string)
     (t (regexp-quote isearch-string)))
    (if current-prefix-arg (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))
  ;; from occur-anything
  (let ((anything-compile-source-functions
         ;; rule out anything-match-plugin because the input is one regexp.
         (delq 'anything-compile-source--match-plugin
               (copy-sequence anything-compile-source-functions))))
    (anything :sources 'anything-c-source-occur
              :input regexp
              :buffer "*Anything Occur*")))
```

Comment: This is very nice, but it's not just `backspace` that's broken -- it looks like the anything keymap isn't enabled, which makes this much less useful.  I don't quite understand how the keymaps work in this case, but it would be cool if this code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar --

In **Icicles**, during Isearch hit `S-TAB`.  Hit `RET` to accept the same search pattern, or edit it first and then hit `RET`.

That opens **Icicles** search with all matches as the search contexts.  To narrow/filter those contexts with a further pattern, just type more text.

To filter progressively with multiple patterns, hit `M-SPC` between patterns.  Cycle among the matches using `C-down` (etc.) or complete to any of them or click `C-mouse-2` on any of them in `*Completions`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Isearch_Enhancements#IciclesSearchFromIsearch